# How to add sub title name in the header using pixture reloaded sub theme of drupal 7.x?

Tags: theming

I need to add sub title name(with different font) next line of the "site name" in the header.
Am using  pixture-reloaded sub theme. could anybody, please help me out, where should i change and what piece of code i should add to diplay it out.

for example: 
site name: Drupal Answers
next line of the site name, i need one more line to display :  Welcome to out job portal.

How can i alter my coding. Please help me out.thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "sub title name" you are referring to is called the "Site Slogan" in Drupal.  In Drupal 7, you can add or edit your site slogan on the Site Information page (/admin/config/system/site-information).

Then, on the Pixture Reloaded settings page, just make sure that the "Site Slogan" checkbox under "Toggle Display" is checked.  You don't need any custom code.